# libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)

Tags: wayland, hardware-acceleration

I encounter this error everywhere since I upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 on wayland. But is this related? Here is the error

```bash
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
```

This error come when I launch chrome `google-chrome --disable-gpu` Or when I try to download a file with google-chrome. Afterwards the browser freeze. This is the same when I want to open AppImage file. What is the link between all of this case?

What can I do about it?

Where should I report the bug?

Is this a wayland problem? A chrome problem? An AppImage problem?

I don't quite get it and I have no idea how to fix it. And even worse, no idea where to go learn something to fix it myself...

If you have any advise please let me know.